# How to prevent running GitHub workflow on master/main

Tags: github, github-actions

I have 2 workflows set up on GitHub:

- pre submit verification (PSV) - should run on every push on every branch **except master**
- submit verification (SV) - should be run only merge to **master**

PSV config:

```
name: Pre Submit Verification Pydriver

on:
  push:
    branches-ignore:
      - master
```

And SV:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
```

Such configuration causes that when I push something to branch that is not the master PSV and SV workflows are run (When I push/merge to master everything works as expected and only SV is run).

I also tried such solution for excluding running SV on branches other than master:

```
on:
  push:
    branches-ignore:
      - '!master'
```

But this also does not work. I would like to avoid conditions in steps to run SV.

Comment: Just a note on why your SV `branches-ignore` rule didn't work: the docs specify that you should use the `branches` filter when you need to filter for both positive matches and exclude some branch names with the `!` prefix. Conversely, you can only use `branches-ignore` for excluding branch names, and cannot use the `!` prefix with this filter. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#excluding-branches-and-tags

Comment: The odd thing is that it seems to me that your rules are set up properly for PSV and SV. Is your repository public so I can see the actions runs?

Comment: Good catch with the `!` and `branches-ignore`. The repository is private at the moment. I have searched a little bit more and it looks that solution given here is working: https://github.community/t/trigger-workflow-only-on-pull-request-merge/17359/8 at least the SV is not run on !master branch.